# Picture unable to be shown in Picture Box from listbox when doing loop C#

Tags: c#, loops, listbox, picturebox

Newbie in programming here so please give answers with clear elaboration. Thank you.

When i do this loop for a slideshow with given number of loops, the pictures do not show in the picturebox while the loop is running.

And, i have a selectedindexchanged event somewhere so only when the loop ends, that event fires and only the last picture is shown on the picturebox.

CODE:

```
if (mtxtloop.Text != "")
{
    int intNumberOfLoops = Convert.ToInt16(mtxtloop.Text);

    for (int intAlbum = 0; intAlbum < intNumberOfLoops; intAlbum++)
    {
       for (int intPictures = 0; intPictures < listBoxPicturesInAlbum.Items.Count; intPictures++)
       {
          //Just to check position.
          listboxPicturesInAlbum.SelectedIndex = intPictures;
          Thread.Sleep(2000);
          //Insert selecteditem into picture
          //ERROR HERE: PictureBox doesn't show selecteditem
          pBoxOfSelectedPicture.Image = Image.FromFile(listBoxPicturesInAlbum.SelectedItem.ToString());
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine and you shouldn't need another thread nor invalidating the picturebox. did you use the debugger to make sure you really hit that last line?

Comment: @TaW yes. used debugger and it hits the last line.

Comment: Hm that is strange. I always use `pBoxOfSelectedPicture.ImageLocation = filename;` but that should both work. When you insert a `string filename= listBoxPicturesInAlbum.SelectedItem.ToString()` do you get the filename you expect? What size and format does the image have? Is any other line in your code set the picturebox's image?

Comment: I am sorry I somehow didn't quite catch what you are doing. Since you are inside a long-running loop you should do a listboxPicturesInAlbum.Refresh();after setting the Image. An Invalidate()somehow doesn't do the trick.. However, sending the UI thread to sleep make the programm unresponsive. You should use a timer instead; then you won't even need the refresh..

Comment: @TaW thanks for your 'string filename= listBoxPicturesInAlbum.SelectedItem.ToString()', it gave me a eureka lol. forgot to put listboxPicturesInAlbum.SelectedIndex = 0 before start of any loop.

Comment: @TaW Well, idk how to when inside loop, fire the timer_tick event once. So i went this route.

Answer (score 1):

In your original code you are simply missing a `PBox_loop.Refresh();`. But you are also tying up the UI thread by sending it to sleep for seconds. Never a good idea.. (`Thread.Sleep()` can sometimes help resolve race conditions but not here and never for more than 10-100ms)

Here is the way I would do it: Use a Timer and three variables at e.g. class level to keep track of the progress..

```
int intNumberOfLoops = 1;
int intLoopCounter = 0;
int pictureIndex = 0;

private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureIndex = 0;
    intLoopCounter = 0;
    // insert error checking here!
    intNumberOfLoops = Convert.ToInt16(mtxtloop.Text);

    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // final image:
    if (intLoopCounter >= intNumberOfLoops)
    {   // this assumes there is a selected item!
        PBox_loop.ImageLocation = listBoxPicturesInAlbum.SelectedItem.ToString();
        timer1.Stop();
        return;
    }

    // the regular loop:
    PBox_loop.ImageLocation = listBoxPicturesInAlbum.Items[pictureIndex];

    pictureIndex++;
    if (pictureIndex >= listBoxPicturesInAlbum.Items.Count)
    {
        pictureIndex = 0;
        intLoopCounter++;
    }
}
```

Using a Timer prevent the UI thread of being blocked without the hassle of starting a Thread of your own..